# Function argument as part of path to a file in Clojure

Tags: csv, clojure

Suppose I have the same file name, placed in five different sub-folders. The file in question has the same name in all folders but otherwise has different values.

Suppose my file is called something like `test.csv`. My folder are `A1,A2,A3,A4` and `A5`.

My data-read structure looks as so:

```
(defn my-data [folder]
  (loop [SUB-FOLDER (str 'folder)
         X []
         data (with-open [file (clojure.java.io/reader "./resources/SUB-FOLDER/test.csv")]
                (doall (csv/read-csv file)))]
    (def row (first data))
    (if (nil? row)
      [(lazy-seq X)]
      (recur (conj X (map #(Float/parseFloat %) row))
             (rest data)))))
```

I would call this function as so

```
(def Y (map vec (get (my-data A1) 0)))
```

Where I am trying to access the file `test.csv` in the sub-folder `A1` which I am passing as an argument to my csv-read function.

Now obviously the above code does not work, but it provides an overview of what I am trying to achieve.

How could one make the minimal example work?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code has many problems. For one, you're trying to read a file literally called ./resources/SUB-FOLDER/test.csv. Reading a csv file is normally very simple, can you give an example of what the contents of a file look like?

Comment: Certainly: the files just contains about 200 rows of (six dimensional) csv data such as: 232.2, 100.5, 12.2, 23.0, 12.2, 90.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should put your data from one folder into a sequence of sequences:

```
(defn read-data [folder]
  (let [data (csv/read-csv (slurp (str "./resources/" folder "/test.csv")))]
    (for [line data]
      (map #(Float/parseFloat %) line))))
```

Change `map` to `mapv` if you want to have vectors, and wrap the `for` with `into []` if you want a vector of vectors. This assumes `folder` is a string. Because your files are very small you don't need to open them with a reader, it's easier to slurp them and then parse them.

A fe issues with your original code:

- You're always trying to read a file called `"./resources/SUB-FOLDER/test.csv"` instead of replacing the name of your folder.
- You don't want to use `def` inside a function. See `let`.
- Calling `lazy-seq` on an already realized sequence doesn't do anything.
- By calling `doall` on your reader you're forcing all your data into memory instead of reading it and processing it as you go (that's why I replaced it with slurp). If you're going to process it in a loop as you read it, you want the `with-open` outside the loop (and no doall).